# replace int in string c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to replace every substring of `int^` with `<int>^`.

For example: if I have the string `"aaa500^bbb"` I want to get the string `"aaa<500>^bbb"`

Comment: Should aaa55^bbb result in aaa<5><5>^bbb or aaa<55>^bbb?

Comment: `(\d+)\^` replace with `<$1>^`

Comment: do you mean replace a regex pattern by another one in c# ?  [read the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) or `Regex.Replace("aaa500^bbb", @"(\d+)\^", @"<$1>^")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good case for a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).

```
Regex.Replace("aaa500^bbb", @"(\d+)\^", @"<$1>^") // aaa<500>^bbb
```

Explaination

- `(\d+)\^` Capture one or more digits that is followed by a caret `^`
- `<$1>^` Replace the captured digits with the captured digits between angled brackets followed by a caret `^`.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

As per my comment...

The regex below works as follows:

- Match one or more digits `\d+` and capture them into group 1
- Match `^`

Replace works as follows:

- Where group 1 was matched, prepend `<` and append `>^`

---

### Code

[You can see this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/iIcT8u/1)

#### Regex

```
(\d+)\^
```

#### Substitution

```
<$1>^
```

---

### Result

#### Input

```
aaa5^bbb
aaa55^bbb
```

#### Output

```
aaa<5>^bbb
aaa<55>^bbb
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this should work (untested).  Can be expanded later to ensure taken value is actually a valid int (and not overflown for example).

```
public static string Do(string myString)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var open = false;
    var digits = new HashSet<char>{'0', '1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    foreach(var c in myString)
    {
        if (digits.Contains(c))
        {
            if (!open)
            {
                sb.Append("<");
                open = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (open)
            {
                open = false;
                sb.Append(">");
            }
        }
        sb.Append(c);
    }
    if (open)
    {
        sb.Append(">");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```